# Python 2.7.1 ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python

I'm trying to resolve this python syntax in version 2.7.1, but I keep receiving the ValueError: too many values to unpack. Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong?

```
import sys  

number_of_outfiles = 100 

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    k = []  
    for i in range(number_of_outfiles):  
        k.append(open('/Users/rootrune/Documents/grand' + str(i) + '.csv','w'))  
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as inf:  
        for i, line in inf:  
            if line[-1] == '\n': line = line[:-1]  
            if i == 0:  
                headers = line  
                [x.write(headers + '\n') for x in k]  
            else:  
                k[i % number_of_outfiles].write(line + '\n')  
    [x.close() for x in k]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File handles are iterators over strings (lines). Your code indicates that you expect (index, line) pairs as they would be produced by [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). So

```
for i, line in inf:
```

should probably be:

```
for i, line in enumerate(inf):
```

Comment: updating it with your suggestion corrected the issue I had. Thank you!